# Can you use display: table-cell and have a fixed width/height?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have the following:

**CSS:**

```
.photo {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**HAML**

```
.photo
  %img{:src => my_url}
```

See the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VMQJG/1/). The image I used to demonstrate is 150px by 80px.

I need to display the image inside the `.photo` div and crop off any excess. The image needs to be centered vertically and horizontally. However, `display:table-cell` causes the `.photo` div to ignore my width and height settings. How can I get around this?

Comment: Can you make the image a `background-image` and adjust the offset to put it in the right place?

Comment: The problem is that the images I'm getting come in various sizes.

Comment: So what is the max height/width the .photo container will expand to? Or will you keep the dimension strictly 100x100?

Comment: @Dan: he width/height of the container needs to be fixed, mu: the sizes are completely random.

Comment: Can you start storing the image dimensions? That would make this easy to solve and would let you use proper `<img>` elements with `width` and `height` attributes.

Comment: Unfortunately these are thousands of images for a photo gallery so storing the dimensions isn't practical.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`table-cell` is not the only solution to vertical-align.

```
.photo {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    display:inline-block; /* or float:left; */
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height:97px;
}
.photo img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: The down-side of this approach is that you need a fixed height and width on `.photo`.

Comment: @Dan-Willis Why would you want to align '.photo img' vertically in '.photo' if '.photo' wasn't a fixed size?

Comment: @Tod sometimes you do not want to set the height of the container. A simple example: simulating things like table rows, the row height (container) has to be of the size of the biggest cell height. In that kind of case, we cannot set height.

Comment: It is when you have mutliple lines

Answer (score 6):

You can use `display: table-cell` but the parent needs to have `display: table-row` and the parent of the row should have `display: table;`

Answer (score 1):

If you put an inner `div` it seems to work. Not sure why you need `display:table-cell` in the first place?

http://jsfiddle.net/locrizak/5tawU/

Also, have you considered just putting a width on the image? This will cause the image's height to also resize accordingly.

Comment: I need display:table-cell for the vertical-align: middle to work.